# How to Trigger a Workflow B start right after Workflow A completed?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am new to Informatica Power Center. 
My task is to trigger/start Workflow B right after when Workflow A just completed using infacmd command.

Suggestion is after all session in workflow a add a command task with "infacmd.sh startworkflow" to start the workflow b with all the options.

I've tried some guides but the version was too old. I'm using Informatica 10.1.1.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fro the command task you can use the following command.
pmcmd startworkflow -sv $INFA_SERVICE -d $INFA_DOMAIN -u $INFRAREPO_USERID -p $INFRAREPO_PASSWD -f $INFA_FOLDER -wait $INFA_WORKFLOW

Replace the variable according to your domain/folder/workflow name etc.

Otherwise, you can create a shell script from where you have to call the workflow using the above command and call the shell script from your last session 'Post Session success command'

Answer (score 0):

Consider creating a `Command task` that will touch a file and having Workflow B started together with Workflow A, with a `Wait task` that will wait for a file, and delete the file as a last step.

This way you don't need to invoke the `pmcmd` with hardcoded username and password.